# Eclipse RCP - SelectionService - History?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am building an Eclipse RCP application that contains some org.eclipse plug-ins in it as well, including the `Project Explorer` view plugin.

Currently in one of my plugins I've implemented a `StartupHook` where I add a listener on the `SelectionService` on the `Project Explorer` view. When my plugin is active, I would like to get the **latest selected project**

Check [this tutorial](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html) for some details on the SelectionService

I would like to NOT use a `StartupHook` for this, because it doesn't really respect the `lazy loading` principle.

Does the SelectionService have a history I could refer to, and search AFTER my plugin has loaded (without prior adding of a listener?)

Comment: No, it does not have a history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SelectionService` has no history.

You will either have to load your plug-in early (and give up on *lazy loading* as you already said) or you can track the selection changes only as soon as your plug-in is activated (if ever).